# npm install bower hangs

Tags: windows, node.js, npm, bower

I'm trying to install bower using npm.

I'm following the instructions and have run the command:

```
npm install -g bower
```

I've also set the loglevel to "info" so I can see what it is doing.

It gets as far as:

```
npm info build \\bedcoll.local\san\Home\Staff\Main\cwarwicker\Profile\AppData\np
m\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer
npm info linkStuff inquirer@0.8.0
npm info install inquirer@0.8.0
npm info postinstall inquirer@0.8.0
```

And then it just stops and hangs. It's been sitting there doing nothing for about 10 minutes now.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Thanks.

If it helps, this is the

Comment: What version of npm are you running? npm -v

Maybe try npm cache clean, then npm install -g bower.

Comment: Version 2.10.1 I just downloaded it this morning to install this bower thing. Tried clearing the cache and it's still getting stuck at the same place.

Comment: looking ad your error read out 'npm info install inquirer@0.8.0'. 
I wonder do you need to run npm install inquirer https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer

Comment: Just tried that, the inquirer install went fine, but bower is still now stuck at the same inquirer place again :(

Comment: Hmm interesting, OK this I got from https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower "Bower depends on Node.js and npm. Also make sure that git is installed as some bower packages require it to be fetched and installed." What node version are you running node -v and have you installed git?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling npm & node? I don't know if it will fix anything but I'd at least try it. It used to fix some weird things when I was still on Windows.

Comment: Just tried reinstalling. It didn't get stuck this time, but it errored instread:

npm info linkStuff inquirer@0.8.0
npm info install inquirer@0.8.0
npm info postinstall inquirer@0.8.0
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (
x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! path \\bedcoll.local\san\Home\Staff\Main\cwarwicker\Profile\AppData\npm
-cache\end-of-stream\1.1.0\package\package.json.55edb6eb3a9a24eb2f2b3585ecde1c39

Comment: npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! errno -4082

npm ERR! EBUSY, rename '\\bedcoll.local\san\Home\Staff\Main\cwarwicker\Profile\A
ppData\npm-cache\end-of-stream\1.1.0\package\package.json.55edb6eb3a9a24eb2f2b35
85ecde1c39'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

your issue looks close the last issue discussed.
i.e. Try removing all the temporary variables other than
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp